# Injected mocked Spring WebServiceTemplate to return predefined value

Tags: spring, web-services

Our web service updated on their end. I updated our client code using Spring web service.

Problem is unit test failed at return since injected mocked WebServiceTemplate returns null.

My question is "Is there a way I can make the return some predefined value?"

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = mock(WebServiceTemplate.class);
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public TheServiceClient client() {
        return new TheServiceClient();
    }

}

public class TheServiceClient {
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    public TheResponse getResponse(TheRequest request) {
        // logic handles the request need to be tested
        JAXBElement<?> element = (JAXBElement<?>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
        return element.getResponse();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class IdalClientTest {
    @Autowired
    private TheServiceClient client;

    @Test
    public void testGetResponse() {
        TheRequest request = new TheRequest();
        request.setters();

        TheResponse response = client.getResponse(request);
        assertThat(response.getSucess()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not injecting the mocked WebServiceTemplate to TheServiceClient.
You should do like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class IdalClientTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TheServiceClient client;

    @Mock
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    @Mock
    JAXBElement jaxBElement;

    @Before
     public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(any(TheRequest.class))).thenReturn(jaxBElement);
     // You can create a TheResponse object with success = true;          
   when(jaxBElement.getResponse()).thenReturn(dummyTheResponseObject);

    }
    @Test
    public void testGetResponse() {
        TheRequest request = new TheRequest();
        request.setters();

        TheResponse response = client.getResponse(request);
        assertThat(response.getSucess()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

You don't need that Configuration class.

Ideal way to do it to use Constructor Injection instead of Field Injection. Like this

```
public class TheServiceClient {

private final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

@Autowired
public TheServiceClient(final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate) {
    this.webServiceTemplate = webServiceTemplate;  
 }
    .......
}
```

Then in your test class instead of InjectMocks you can do like this

```
private TheServiceClient client;

@Mock
WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;


@Before
 public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    client = new TheServiceClient(webServiceTemplate);
       .............
}
 ................
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still do not know how to make the mocked WebServiceTemplate returns predefined value

Comment: I will accept the answer, though I could not make it return predefined value after rewrote all related classes